# How to run tasks from db with Quartz Cron expression in java?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I'm trying to create a file backup application with background scheduled tasks. User can create a lot of plans for backup files with different schedules.

When I develop a sample, I get an interesting result.

every tasks loading successfully but just last plan works. here is my results:

```
plan_1 created...
plan_6 created...
plan_11 created...
plan_16 created...
plan_16 executed!
plan_16 executed!
plan_16 executed!
plan_16 executed!
plan_16 executed!
....
```

This class for my plans..

```
public class BasePlan {
    private String name;
    private String filePath;
    private String schedule;
    private boolean state;

    public BasePlan() {
    }
}
```

This is created plans in db..

```
public class DummyData {
        public static List<BasePlan> getWaitingPlans() {
            List<BasePlan> planList = new ArrayList<BasePlan>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i += 5) {
                planList.add(new BasePlan("plan_" + i, "0/" + i + " * * * * ?", false, randomFilePath));
            }
            return planList;
        }
    }
```

This class for backing up progress

```
    public class BackupJobFactory implements Job {
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
            // this method will back up files in different time.
            try {
                SchedulerContext schedulerContext = context.getScheduler().getContext();
                BasePlan plan = (BasePlan) schedulerContext.get("plan");
                plan.setState(true);
                System.out.println(plan.getName() + " executed!");
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is main class

```
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException, ParseException {
        for (BasePlan plan : DummyData.getWaitingPlans()) {

            System.out.println(plan.getName() + " created...");
            JobBuilder jobBuilder = JobBuilder.newJob(BackupJobFactory.class);
            JobDetail job = jobBuilder.withIdentity(plan.getName(), plan.getName()).build();
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(plan.getSchedule()))
                    .build();

            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.getContext().put("plan", plan);
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you create the scheduler outside the for loop and use the same instance to schedule the jobs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code like that, and works fine!

```
for (BasePlan plan : DummyData.getWaitingPlans()) {

            System.out.println(plan.getName() + " created...");
            JobBuilder jobBuilder = JobBuilder.newJob(BackupJobFactory.class);
            JobDetail job = jobBuilder.withIdentity(plan.getName(), plan.getName()).build();
            job.getJobDataMap().put("basePlan", plan);

            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(plan.getSchedule()))
                    .build();

            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }
```